# how to debug a flask app when running in docker

Tags: docker, flask

I want to debug functions in a Flask app so I added some `logger.info()` in the code. I then have to run this app in a docker container. How can I view the logger info (like flask.log)? Because I cannot see these logs in the terminal.

I have tried use debug mode.

```
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN: 105-605-483
172.17.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2019 09:10:21] "POST /?utm_src=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Can you show your complete piece of code? Are you using the Python `logging` package?

Answer (score 0):

You could always [mount a host created volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes) in the container, that way flask could write its log there, and you could access it on the host.

Or you could start the docker without the entrypoint, and run the flask app manually. Something in the lines of `docker run -it container_name:tag /bin/bash`